# How can I decrypt a password stored in CiviCRM?

Tags: civimail, passwords

I've added a mail account at **Administer » System Settings » Outgoing Email**.  I don't know the password, but I need it.  How can I get ahold of it?

Answer (score 3):

First - you must have command-line access, the `cv` utility installed, and database access. This also assumes modern CiviCRM, where you have `CIVICRM_CRED_KEYS` defined in your `civicrm.settings.php`.

Check the database for the record that contains your password with the following SQL:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(value, 'smtpPassword.*') FROM civicrm_setting WHERE name = 'mailing_backend';
```

You should get back something like this:

```
MariaDB [my_database]> SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(value, 'smtpPassword.*') FROM civicrm_setting WHERE name = 'mailing_backend';
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| REGEXP_SUBSTR(value, 'smtpPassword.*')                                                                                        |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| smtpPassword";s:101:"CTK?k=dxBmEYKu9NyzrI1vngkmrxtqUL4&t=NuDgeEtjXFvxYWwAYii0S2GZqSfcpWS5G7d6DF1souXWmxixnQMwrH46tV_oqRLy";} |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.000 sec)
```

The encrypted password is in quotes, starting with `CTK`.  If it does NOT start with `CTK`, it's not encrypted - that's your password.

If it *is* encrypted, run the following command on your command line:

```
cv ev '$k = new \Civi\Crypto\CryptoToken(); $t = $k->decrypt("\x02" . "<encrypted password here>"); echo $t'
```

For instance, using the example above:

```
cv ev '$k = new \Civi\Crypto\CryptoToken(); $t = $k->decrypt("\x02" . "CTK?k=dxBmEYKu9NyzrI1vngkmrxtqUL4&t=89TTC7izYJ5KemXD4Pf8QckyMKvJ4RJcSQM2ejZPlx0HgUVYQguv_yJJn22QAuri"); echo $t'
```

The password will be returned on the command line.  Note that you MUST be running this command using the same `CIVICRM_CRED_KEYS` setting in `civicrm.settings.php` that existed when the key was encrypted.